# Multilingual website with distinct font types

Tags: css, umbraco, multilingual

I'm developing my website with Umbraco, and I need it to be multilingual with both english and chinese. To make my website multilingual with Umbraco I basically have the website cloned and then changing the contents, but keeping all the html and css templates. 
But for the chinese version I will need to use a different font type, how can I do this? Is it possible to specify which font to use in the CSS? Or any other solution?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You mean a different font _family_? If so, read [`unicode-range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range) which is what you need.

Comment: But if that's not what you meant, please explain what you do need; what goes wrong. Browsers are usually pretty good at displaying Chinese characters without having to take special measurements.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you add a class to the `body` based on the language? For example `en` for English and `cn` for Chinese? Then you can target `body.en` and `body.cn` and add different fonts based on those.

Example:

```
body.cn {
   font-family: 'chinese font';
}

body.en {
   font-family: 'english font';
}
```

Comment: The html file is the same for both, that would work if I had 2 different html files, I think. Unless I'm not really understanding your answer.

Comment: You can probably let Umbraco add the class, based on what language is being shown. There must be a `if (*check for language*) { do something }` in Umbraco. See it as Wordpress adding `home`, `post` and `page` to the `body` class, depending on what page you are viewing. That way, you can write very specific CSS.

Comment: You will have to change your template somehow. What @Rvervuurt suggests is a very simple addition to the body tag, something like <body class="@Model.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName"> (but I don't know your Umbraco version or how your templates/views are set up, so it's an approximation).

Comment: Oh ok, I understand now! It looks like a simple solution, I'll try it!

Answer (score 0):

```css
body,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  color: #2b2b2b;
  font: 12px/1.5 "Hiragino Sans GB", Tahoma, Arial, Microsoft YaHei, "微软雅黑", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  *font-family: "Hiragino Sans GB", Microsoft YaHei, "微软雅黑", Tahoma, Arial, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
```

Put your english font-family before chinese, so chinese computer only recongnize the chinese font-family and ignore the english font-family.
I am a web developer form China, Chinese font-family is very little:
1. 微软雅黑(microsoft yahei)
2. 宋体(simsun)
3. 黑体

Answer (score 0):

Use the Culture to add the "lang"-attribute to the HTML-tag, then in the CSS, select it by using html[lang="CULTURE"]. So for English, you use e.g. "en-GB", producing the following:

Razor (layout page):

```
<html lang="@Culture">
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html[lang="en-GB"] { font-family: 'WhatEverFont', sans-serif; }
```

Or, you can achieve this by adding the Culture as a class to your body, e.g.:

Razor (layout page):

```
<html lang="@Culture">
  <body class="@Culture.ToLower()">
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body.en-gb { font-family: 'WhatEverFont', sans-serif }
```